# Add new lines to make links vertically alignment

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

ASP.NET MVC 2 Project.

I want the links to the view vertically aligned. Should I add br or \n something?

Thanks.

```
               <div class="links">
                    <%=Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home") %>
                    <%=Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home") %>
               </div>
```

For instance.

```
               <div class="links">
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <%=Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home") %>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <%=Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home") %>
               </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean "vertically aligned"?  Do you want them centered?  spaced out?  using line breaks like this isn't the best way to do something like this.

Comment: you want them vertically aligned inside the div with class "links"?

Comment: Set your links to display: block; and then you can mess with your margins from there.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I mean that each link each line. I need line break.

Comment: display: block in CSS doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using what you have right now you could apply some CSS:

```
div.links a {
    display: block;
}
```

This would put each link on its own line.

Comment: No, no, it works for <a> in pure html, but not working for Html.ActionLink. It is the feature of MVC

Comment: Html.ActionLink translates into an <a> tag in MVC. Inspect the HTML, you will see.

Comment: It has one line break for each link. If I want more line breaks, how to do it?

Comment: Just add `margin-bottom:10px;` or something like that to that class.